# Muted headphone jack, but if I replug in headphones I need to go into alsamixer and unmute it again

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

When I plug my headphones into my laptop (HP dv6 6176sa), I can get no sound through them, while the laptop's speakers work perfectly.

I managed to fix this by opening alsamixer and seeing that when I plug in my headphones the 'speakers' become muted, I unmuted them and increased the volume, my headphones worked. However I then unplugged them, and plugged them back in, and once again speakers became muted and 0 volume.

Why does this occur and how can I fix it so that I don't have to go into Alsamixer every time I want to use headphones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound muted when headphones are connected in 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72492/sound-muted-when-headphones-are-connected-in-11-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, if you don't see the option to turn off auto mute you probably have the same alsa version as me, follow this guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS and its fixed, working perfectly!